# regular expression Help on - extract a value from a string ignoring the previous contents

Tags: java, regex

can someone help me to write a java regex to retrieve a value from the following string please?

```
XX0001  15NOV XXX SELECTED RAX                                       AXXXXX DXXXXXXXXX           REF NBR  002            SSSS
```

I wanted to extract the value 002. All the strings / characters before 002 are fixed length and properly padded with trailing space (if req.).  could have any string/numeric/special displayable characters.

I am looking for something like ... get 002 from that position ignoring whatever before. ?

Comment: Well, what have you got so far?

Comment: What language? You don't need a regex. If the position is fixed, you just need to get a substring of length 3 starting from a certain position.

Comment: @arungnair, OK, I saw your comment below in npinti's answer. But I don't understand. Why do you need to use a regex for this? Is this homework?

Comment: Jonathan, No it is not homework. Its a requirement i am currently implementing and there is already a regEx based parser in place. And, I need to parse set of string for specfic values. Could have been done better with various ways, but currently regex is the only option i have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the last set of digits before the end of the string, you might want to do something like this:

```
^.*\\d{3}\\s+.{4}$
```

This should instruct the Regex Engine to start matching from the beginning of the string, match any characters and then, from the end, match 3 numbers, a space and any 4 characters.

Also, if you have fixed sizes and lengths, you can most likely get away with a [.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method, it is less complex.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been bit more clear. As many suggested before java would be easy. But, i need to use an existing java regex framework and had to use that to build a parser regular expression pattern. So, java is not an option, so needed to write some regular expression to reach the position and take the numeric value. the bit, I am stuck with how to write a pattern to 'read 8 character block (number/chrs/special chrs), then read next 6 .. so on till i reach the 002 ? may be wrong approach ...

Comment: With regex you can start reading from the end, which is what the regex I propose does.

Answer (score 0):

What language?

If javascript:

```
myCode=myString.substring(56,58);
```

or

```
myCode=myString.substr(56,3);
```

If PHP:

```
$myCode=substr($myString,56,3);
```

This simpler option is preferable to regex because it is faster. You can use this because you're working with fixed length strings.

EDIT: Just saw your edit referencing Java. So in Java:

```
String myCode = myString.substring(56,59);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to do that. Just use the `String` method  `substring`:

```
String myString = originalString.substring(106,109); // myString = "002"
```

106 is the begin index, and 109 the end index - 1. To simply get the first, just take the length of the original string just before the number you want to get, for instance:

```
System.out.println("XX0001  15NOV XXX SELECTED RAX                                       AXXXXX DXXXXXXXXX           REF NBR  ".length());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java

```
string.substring(56,59);
```

Comment: So he edits his original question and I get downvoted because my answer no longer applies. Seems stupid...